# Using CakePHP model class

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm just studying CakePHP so sorry for any obvious mistakes. 
I have created model class and changed default table name.

```
class Weathers extends AppModel {    
    public $tablePrefix = 'weather_';
    public $useTable = 'forecasts';

    function saveCountries($countries){
         ...
    }
}
```

And my controller function

```
if (!$this->loadModel('Weather'))
   exit;
$Weather = $this->Weather;
$Weather->saveCountries($countries);
```

I'm getting error on *$Weather->saveCountries($countries)*;

> Error: Table weathers for model Weather was not found in datasource
>   default.

Please help find out what I do wrong.

Comment: Model class names should be singular. Do `debug(get_class($Weather));` it will most likely be `AppModel` and not `Weathers` as you have it now.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried and it doesn't help. And the result for debug is `AppModel`

Comment: Change the class name to `Weather` and the file name to `Weather.php`. What happens is if cake can't find your model, it creates one based off of AppModel

Comment: Yes, the problem was with filename. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model class you defined is `Weathers` not `Weather`.  So just change the class name `Weather` instead of `Weathers` and this is done.

Answer (score 1):

Note the declaration of your Model class.

You've called it `Weathers`.

There is no problem with this. However, as you are trying to then load the model `Weather` (not the lack of plural in this case) CakePHP is constructing a model dynamically for you, instead of using your `Weathers` (plural) class.

The CakePHP standard is to use a singular name for models. I suggest that you rename your model class to `Weather` to avoid this issue. Once you make this change, the code that you have for loading the model will work as intended.